# how to show Generic in swagger

Tags: java, swagger-2.0

I have the below code:
@ApiModel(value = "SearchResult", description = "Search result object")
public class SearchResult {

```
@ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "Search results")
@Setter
@Getter
List<T> item;
```

}

my controller is returning ResponseEntity>

I have Test.java and all the fields are annotated by @ApiModelProperty
but the swager is showing me :

item (Array[Inline Model 1]): Search results ,

my question here is how to see the Test.java in swagger??

Comment: ResponseEntity<SearchResult<Test>>